# Facing issue while link snowboy with google assistant

Tags: python-3.x, google-assistant-sdk

> i facing the problem while running the commands to link snowboy with google assistant, i dont understand what error and how to resolve this please give some solution for this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "demo.py", line 1, in 
    import snowboydecoder
  File "/home/pi/hestia/snowboy/examples/Python3/snowboydecoder.py", line 7, in 
    import snowboydetect
  File "/home/pi/hestia/snowboy/examples/Python3/snowboydetect.py", line 17, in 
    _snowboydetect = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/pi/hestia/snowboy/examples/Python3/snowboydetect.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_snowboydetect')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
    **import**(name)
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_snowboydetect)

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue. fixed it by running demo.py using python2

python2 demo.py snowboy.umdl